# How to perform likelihood ratio test for bayesian neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, bayesian, model-evaluation, likelihood-ratio

I am building a Bayesian neural network with Poisson likelihood and 50 features for time series prediction. Parameters of the model are learned using variational inference. I am trying to see whether adding a new feature will improve the model. For this, my first thought was to perform likelihood ratio test since this is a nested model, but that requires maximum likelihood estimate but how do I make sure that the model is able to find the parameters that maximize likelihood or is that not possible? What other test is possible to check if the new feature added is making a significant effect or not?